# Is there a way to match users based on their location?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Essentially I am hoping to have the app register the location of user A who is actively using the app. Then register the location of user B who is also active and then match them if they are within a 20 mile radius.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this using [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator). Please follow all the instruction mention in geolocator.

Then import geolocator.

`import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';`

```dart
Future<double> calculateDistance(double startLatitude,double startLongitude) async{

    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);//get user's current location

    double endLatitude = position.latitude;
    double endLongitude = position.longitude;

    double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(startLatitude,startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude);

    return distanceInMeters * 0.000621371192;//convert meters into miles.
}
```

You need to check if user granted the location permission.